Как найти все корни системы уравнений в gnu octave?
Возникла такая проблема, по заданию нужно найти корни через ф-цию solve, сйчас, как я понял используестся fsolve, соответственно мы создаем объект function и задаем вектор, но находим 1 корень, ближайший к вектору, соответственно вопрос. В теории мы создаем график и примерно зная точки, пишем вектора и находим точки, как в этом случае
x = -10: 0.1 :10;
y=8./x
plot(x,y)
hold on
y=8-x.^2
plot(x,y,"k");
xlim([-5,5]);
ylim([-20;20])
grid on;
function y = f3(x)
  y(1) = 8./x(1)-x(2);
  y(2) = 8-x(1).^2-x(2);
endfunction
fsolve(@f3, [-5,0])
fsolve(@f3, [1.9,2])
fsolve(@f3, [1,1.9])

но есть ли способ найти сразу все корни (если в векторе написать 0,0, мы найдем ближайший). Если более конкретно, можно ли решить систему из x^3-2*y=1, 3x+3y^2=2 не строя график (1 решение найти легко, а надо найти все)

Эта система сводится к одному многочлену одной переменной. А для них Октава умеет искать все корни.
